Facing issue while creating Chat App using WebSocket in React
I'm new to React and working on a React project - to build chat application. The logic is when new user logs in, all users name are displayed on the screen. This is done by events. When user logs in client sends "newUser" to server and then server broadcast "newUserResponse" event to all connected clients by passing users name.
I'm facing issue while displaying the names on screen. The event "newUserResponse" is triggering each time when user logs in. I observed that this event is not being fired when user logs in first time and count is 1. When other users logs in there it's displaying all count.
Index.js(server side)
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const connectDB = require("./utils/dbConnect");
const cors = require("cors");
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const PORT = 4000;
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
// const socketIO = require("socket.io")(http, {
//   cors: {
//     origin: "http://localhost:3000",
//   },
// });
// Initialize environment variables
dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000", // React's port
  credentials: true, // Allows cookies to be sent
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cookieParser());
connectDB();

// WebSocket setup
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socketIO = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

let users = [];

socketIO.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`⚡: ${socket.id} user just connected!`);
  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    socketIO.emit("messageResponse", data);
  });

  socket.on("typing", (data) => socket.broadcast.emit("typingResponse", data));

  socket.on("newUser", (data) => {
    users.push(data);
    socketIO.emit("newUserResponse", users);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(": A user disconnected");
    users = users.filter((user) => user.socketID !== socket.id);
    socketIO.emit("newUserResponse", users);
    socket.disconnect();
  });
});

// API Routes
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hello" });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});


Home component is React which sends the event to server
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import axios from "axios";

const Home = ({ socket }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  // Set up socket listener (only once on mount)
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("addUser", (users) => {
      console.log("addUser event received:", users);
    });

    // Clean up socket listener on unmount
    return () => {
      socket.off("addUser");
    };
  }, [socket]);

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      console.log("Submitting form data:", data);

      // Make the API call
      const response = await axios.get(
        "http://localhost:4000/api/users/",
        { params: data }, // For GET requests, send data via params
        { withCredentials: true }
      );

      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log("API call successful, response:", response.data);

        // Save username locally
        localStorage.setItem("userName", data.email);

        // Emit socket event after ensuring API call succeeds
        console.log("Emitting newUser event");
        socket.emit("newUser", { userName: data.email, socketID: socket.id });

        // Navigate to the chat page
        navigate("/chat");
      } else {
        console.error("Unexpected response status:", response.status);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        "Error during API call or socket operation:",
        error.message
      );
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form className="home__container" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <h2 className="home__header">Sign in to Open Chat</h2>

      <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="username"
        className="username__input"
        {...register("email", { required: "Username is required" })}
        placeholder="Enter your username"
      />
      {errors.email && <p className="error-message">{errors.email.message}</p>}

      <br />
      <input
        type="password"
        id="password"
        className="username__input"
        {...register("password", { required: "Password is required" })}
        placeholder="Enter your password"
      />
      {errors.password && (
        <p className="error-message">{errors.password.message}</p>
      )}

      <button className="home__cta" disabled={loading}>
        {loading ? "Loading..." : "SIGN IN"}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Home;


Chat Bar component which renders the logged in username
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ChatBar = ({ socket }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Add listener for the addUser event
    const handleAddUser = (data) => {
      console.log("Updated users list received:", data);
      setUsers(data); // Update the users list
    };

    socket.on("newUserResponse", handleAddUser);

    // Clean up the listener on component unmount
    return () => {
      console.log("Cleaning up the chatbar");
      socket.off("newUserResponse", handleAddUser); // Remove the specific listener
    };
  }, [socket, users]); // Dependency array ensures this runs only once

  return (
    <div className="chat__sidebar">
      <h2>Open Chat</h2>
      <div>
        <h4 className="chat__header">ACTIVE USERS</h4>
        <div className="chat__users">
          {users.map((user) => (
            <p key={user.socketID}>{user.userName}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatBar;


Github link - https://github.com/razak7860/Chat-App
I would like to know what is the issue and how we can fix it.

Can anyone please help me on this?
